Get the name of the external user who edits a cell in google sheets
The code below, from Google Apps Script, records the date (column J) and the user (column H) who edits a cell in column "E" in Google Sheets. However, the script only gets the user if they are a Google user. External users, with a Microsoft domain, for example, do not have their users recorded.
Is there any function other than Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); what solves this?
    function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  if (sheet.getName() == "sheet1" && range.getColumn() == 5) {

    if (e.value === "") {
      return;
    }
    
    var currentDate = new Date();
    
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
    
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
        var row = range.getRow() + i - 1;
        var colDate = 10;
        var dateCell = sheet.getRange(row, colDate);
        dateCell.setValue(formattedDate);
        var userCol = 11;
        var userCell = sheet.getRange(row, userCol);
        userCell.setValue(user);
      }
    }
  }
}

Test worksheet:
Test
